# Using algebra in SQL with CASE statement

Tags: sql, case, multiplication, algebra

I'm trying to use different algebraic expressions (+,-,*,/) with CASE statement but I'm having some trouble.

Basically the syntax is that, if the currency is GBp (little p means pence) I want it to be multiplied by 100 so that it becomes GBP (i.e. pence into pounds)

Here is my query. I think I'm missing something simple!

---

```
select Currency, FXrate
case 
    when Currency = 'GBp' 
    then FXrate = FXrate * 100 
    end  
from FXdatabase
```

Comment: whats the error you getting , instead of = did u try using like operator ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results really help.

Comment: Can you provide the syntax you have done so far please

Comment: You want to lose the `FXrate =` from inside the case statement. You're also missing a comma or = before the `case` keyword in your query.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select Currency,
       (case when Currency = 'GBp' then FXrate * 100 else FXrate
        end) as FXrate
from FXdatabase;
```

Comment: I posted almost the same answer (except the `else` part), and cause i am second, i deleted mine and upvoted this.

Comment: Hello Gordan and thank you for your quick response! I updated my query(basically copy and pasted yours) and I'm getting the following error: "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Do I need another expression somewhere?

Comment: You want to lose the `FXrate =` from inside the case statement.